# Does hardhat-trace work on localhost?

Tags: hardhat, ethereumjs, hardforks

I'm trying to troubleshoot my hardhat project's smart contract, but every time I run `npx hardhat trace --hash [transaction hash]` I get the error `Transaction not found on rpc.`

This has me wondering if a can use trace to debug a smart contract when I'm on a localhost fork?

Here's an example error:

```
npx hardhat trace --hash 0xe5b4e582ab2369885c08a0846e41b76b3082b86e931d906879393c95a48fbcfd --network hardhat
Nothing to compile
An unexpected error occurred:

Error: [hardhat-tracer]: Transaction not found on rpc. Are you sure the transaction is confirmed on this network?
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/Users/Me/dfsBot/node_modules/hardhat-tracer/src/tasks/trace.ts:105:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (/Users/Me/dfsBot/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:358:14)
    at Environment.run (/Users/Me/dfsBot/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:191:14)
    at main (/Users/Me/dfsBot/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/cli/cli.ts:323:7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to trace your transaction on localhost forking, you should point your network into localhost instead of hardhat.

Hardhat network is run in process while localhost node is run standalone.

When you run `npx hardhat console`, you will access hardhat network and everything you do will exist until you close that console.

But when you do `npx hardhat console --network localhost`, you deployed or run some transactions, close console, open again, everything is still exist.